# Как выровнять их без костылей?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, позиционирование

Есть два блока и их нужно как-то выровнять по центру.
https://jsfiddle.net/ert2x0u1/19/

```css
.con {
  border: 2px solid red;
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.elem {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.elem_active {
  transform: scale(2.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="elem">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="elem elem_active">Lorem ipsum.</div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: Вроде ровно стоят...

Comment: Чтобы они оба стояли как второй блок